# passing data between c++ and nodejs

Tags: c++, node.js, v8, node-modules

The following code snippet is causing issued after upgrading node from v0.12 to v6.11

```
vector<char> buf;
// code that populates the vector

Local<Object> nbuf = Buffer::New(args.GetIsolate(), &buf[0], buf.size());

//return buffer to node    
args.GetReturnValue().Set(scope.Escape(nbuf));
```

The node upgrade implied having to change:

```
Local<Object> nbuf = Buffer::New(args.GetIsolate(), &buf[0], buf.size());
```

to:

```
Local<Object> nbuf = Buffer::New(args.GetIsolate(), &buf[0], buf.size()).ToLocalChecked());
```

The problem is that when printing out the content of the buffer in node the contents are not the same. 
So the questions is: how can I get the same behaviour as I had in node v0.12 when using node v6.11?

UPDATE: after some research I found the underlying problem - Buffer:New calls ArrayBuffer::New which builds an arrayBuffer on top of the exiting memory buffer, so when that goes out of scope the buffer only contains whatever is on the stack. In node-v0.12 Buffer:New was creating a copy of the data which it owned.
The problem is I still don't know how to get the same behaviour using node-v6

Comment: What does `ToLocalChecked()` intend to do?

Comment: @CinCout it part of the node API ; converts a MaybeLocal<Object> to Local<Object>

Comment: Just curious, why do you use `&buf[0]` instead of just `buf`?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts buf reffers to the vector object &buf[0] is the start of the underlying array

Comment: @Pandrei oh! That makes sense. Thanks for the clarification. So instead of `std::vector<T>` it's `T*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

posting this just in case anyone ever comes across the same issue:

the issue is that between node 0.12 and node v6 the implementation of Buffer::New(...)

```
MaybeLocal<Object> New(Isolate* isolate, const char* data, size_t length)
```

has changed: in node 0.12 it used to call memcpy while for node v6 is just calls `ArrayBuffer::New(env->isolate(), data, length)` and this does not copy the data. According to the documentation:

> static Local v8::ArrayBuffer::New    (   Isolate *   isolate, 
>   void *    data, size_t    byte_length )
>
> Create a new ArrayBuffer over an
>   existing memory block. The  created array buffer is immediately in
>   externalized state. The memory   block will not be reclaimed when a
>   created ArrayBuffer is garbage-  collected.

So the the locally created vector which the ArrayBuffer was built on top of, goes out of scope you are left with whatever is on the stack...which was pretty much what I saw.

Solution: call `Buffer::Copy(args.GetIsolate(), &buf[0], buf.size());`

Answer (score 0):

Your `ToLocalChecked()` is on the wrong object. Correct would be:

`Local<Object> nbuf = Buffer::New(args.GetIsolate(), &buf[0], buf.size()).ToLocalChecked();`

Comment: sorry that was a typo; it actually is on the correct object